# Magento 2 No such entity with cartid =

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, cart, error

I'm experiencing this error on my site quite often:

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId =

It's not using multiple stores, so the entity_ids are not an issue as stated in many other solutions I have tried.

I can't find anything helpful anywhere else.

Comment: Where have you this error, in which page ? did you make some changes recently ?

Comment: Literally aftering adding a product to the cart and going to cart from the product page we get this error. Haven't made any changes to the checkout files recently.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade magento version ?

Comment: So when you add a product to cart, a product is added well to cart and when you go to cart you have this message and the cart is not displayed right

Comment: That's correct Prince yeah and no Pawan I'm using the latest version

Comment: When your cart is empty, the problem persists ?

Comment: No only when adding a product to the cart

Comment: Try to create a new product, reindex all, clear the cache, then try again with this new product, if it doesn't work check this : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6522, try also with a loggin user and not loggin

Comment: It's still not working, I'll see if I can't find a work around, will update this post if I do

Comment: Did you find a solution @Howliee?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Firefox plugin uMatrix was causing the issue.

I described it [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5847#issuecomment-496153411):

> I had the same issue using paypal.
> Magento 2.2.8 iways paypal plus module
> multisite setup
>
> Every time I confirmed the checkout on the
> paypal site I ended up in the cart with the message "no such entity
> with cart id =".
>
> It turned
> out that uMatrix is the trouble maker in my case. Even when disabling
> it for my particular site it caused the error. Only after completely
> disabling it in the addons the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an email sending issue. The email config was trying to send from ABC@domain as XYZ@domain.

I changed to send from ABC@domain with a BCC XYC@domain and all is well again